# Shutdown Logstash when using pipeline-to-pipelines communication

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I would like to refactor my Logstash pipelines by using one of the pipeline-to-pipeline architecture patterns (the forked path pattern). The input of the upstream pipeline is a one-time query to an Elasticsearch cluster, using the elasticsearch input plugin. The number of inputs to downstream is therefore finite.

However, when the downstream pipelines have consumed and processed all the inputs, Logstash does not shut down - as it does, when I don't use pipeline-to-pipelines communication.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there a way to shut down Logstash when all the downstream pipelines have processed all the events coming from upstream?

Thanks

> (I originally asked this question on [discuss.elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/shutdown-logstash-when-using-pipeline-to-pipelines-communication/205431), but I got no reply)

### Update 26.06.2020

Till today, I couldn't find any working solution. I asked the same question at the latest Elastic{ON}, but they couldn't give me an answer. So here I am again to the community!

[Looking at the Logstash code](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/e9c9865f4066b54048f8d708612a72d25e2fe5d9/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/builtin/pipeline/output.rb), I don't see any parameter to request Logstash termination once (1) the upstream pipeline has sent out all the event s and (2) all downstream pipelines have consumed all the sent events.

If this is the intended behaviour, do you know what is the rationale behind it, and how I can hack around it?

Comment: Hi @glenacota did you find any way to shut down logstash after completion of processing?

Comment: Unfortunately, no